# Google assistant note： the device does not support remote control

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

reference link: https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/embed/setup

1.According to the reference link, I realized the light control on raspberryPi.

2.when I run pushtotalk.py, I can control testlight on/off via resberry mic.

3.When I via Google assistant apk to control testlight on/off, it prompts me "testlight does not support remote control"

4.When I turned off the raspberryPi's board and ran the Google assistant APK to control testLight, it still prompted me "testlight does not support remote control"

**so i think,testLight should always be offline and displayed in Google assistant apk.
I need some help, I don't know what else to setting or to do to make it online.**